# Reading array-like values from .INI file into PHP array? Example inside

Tags: php, arrays, ini

I searched similar questions but found nothing quite did what I want.

I have a large INI file which contains basic key/value pairs on each line. Lots of the keys are basically "arrays" stored in .INI format as you'll see in the excerpt below:

```
# Excerpt from INI file itself...
CountryFlagsPackage=CountryFlags
bAllowBinds=False
bShowTime=False
Records[0]=14.64
Records[1]=16.33
Records[2]=11.47
Records[3]=13.26
Records[4]=16.64
Records[5]=19.34
```

I'm using parse_ini_string() to put the INI into an array which results in this:

```
# Excerpt from print_r() after parse_ini_string()
[CountryFlagsPackage] => CountryFlags
[bAllowBinds] => False
[bShowTime] => False
[Records[0]] => 14.64
[Records[1]] => 16.33
[Records[2]] => 11.47
[Records[3]] => 13.26
[Records[4]] => 16.64
[Records[5]] => 19.34
```

My question is: is there an elegant way to group all those "Records" entries into one PHP array? Currently - as you see above - they're just individual array items. Basically, I'm looking for the above array to become multi-dimensional.

I could use array_keys() and look for the text "Records" but that's not very elegant or re-usable.

Edit: I suppose I could use a regex to look for anything with square brackets at the end, too. Any better solutions?

Comment: is this the entire ini file or just part of it? there is nothing wrong with your proposed solution assuming this is the entire file.

Comment: @BrianGlaz It's just part of a very large file which is why I wanted that flexibility. I should have mentioned that. I'll edit my question to include the actual .INI text, too, not just PHP's array-ed version. Thanks.

Comment: i've never worked with `parse_ini_string()` but according to the docs, if you pass `true` as the 2nd parameter, it's supposed to return a multidimensional array. did you try this already?

Comment: I think you'll have to write your own file reading loop, rather than use parse_ini_string(), and eval the keys as you go . . .

Comment: @BrianGlaz I tried that, but all it does is separate the INI sections (e.g. lines inside [Square Brackets] which act like headers to break up the file). The key/values remain in the same flat structure as above.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a native way to do this, so here's what I did:

```
$file = parse_ini_string($ini);

foreach ($file as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/(\w+)\[\d+]/", $key, $matches)) {
        // "Array" style key/value
        $arrays[$matches[1]][] = $value;
    } else {
        // Standard key/value pair
        $arrays[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($arrays);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [CountryFlagsPackage] => CountryFlags
    [bAllowBinds] => False
    [bShowTime] => False
    [Records] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14.64
            [1] => 16.33
            [2] => 11.47
            [3] => 13.26
            [4] => 16.64
            [5] => 19.34
        )
)
```